# Install apk file silently on rooted android device programatically without asking from user

Tags: android, installation, apk, rooted-device

I need to download apk file from server to device and then install it silently without any user interaction. I'm using a rooted android device. Is it possible to do? Is there any way I could do that?

I used following code to install the apk. But it asks from user to press Install or cancel.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(sdcard,"Android/data/com.mycompany.android.games/temp/temp.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Luckily what you want is impossible.

Comment: What I need is download and install app update without user interaction on rooted device. Can't a rooted device do that :(

Comment: `"install it (update) silently without any user interaction"` That would break the security that Android put in place to stop malware.

Comment: Yes true, but I thought it is possible in rooted ones. Anyway Thanks guys....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Android system app, silent update without Google play on rooted device.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936361/install-android-system-app-silent-update-without-google-play-on-rooted-device)

Answer (score 0):

What I did so far is https://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/how-to-install-a-application-in-background-on-android/ 
and it is working fine for my case.

One point, my application is running on non-rooted device and I signed my app by device manufacturer's platform key.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to know.