# Android: All ways for app update silently

Tags: android, auto-update, android-install-apk, silent-installer

We try to find some method for update our app silently (without user prompt). The methods that we already saw and they didn't help me:

1. Google Play Store - not relevant for our app (not match Google conditions)
2. [Root device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936361/install-android-system-app-silent-update-without-google-play-on-rooted-device) - not relevant for production (almost all our phones without root)
3. [Install/update by system app (without root)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619693/silent-install-apk-programmatically-by-system-app-without-root#comment44556469_15660063) - not relevant for production (we have many different phones)
4. [Device owner](https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/dev-admin/set-dev-owner) - not relevant for production (need factory reset - [Making my app a device owner doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489427/making-my-app-a-device-owner-doesnt-work))
5. [Accessibility Service](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3972#!description) - very tricky way and doesn't work when screen is off or locked

Maybe does an another method exist? Can somebody help us with this?

**We speak only about UPDATES installation. Initial installation user will do by himself.**

Comment: Make it a progressive web app instead of native android app

Comment: you can't update app silently (except the app being a system app, or using root). Even device owner app (as I know) can't update **itself** silently, only other apps.

Comment: @VivekMishra What does it mean " a progressive web app"? It's like dynamic modules that can be called in reflection?

Comment: no it's web technology based application which you can say is a type of mobile optimised website

Comment: @VivekMishra Can I use all android features in this way? Like AccessibilityService? Will I have access to user data in this way? Which link do you recommend to read? Thank you

Comment: I haven't created any of these apps but this should get you started https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp

Comment: If you are making app for enterprise where some organization wants to update some app silently then https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements/fully-managed-device will help you.

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue recently, and another way to achieve it is In-App Updates. But is not silently at all.